# Internal API in PHP, alternatives to include?

Tags: php, api, http, curl

I've got 1 server with more than ten different standalone applications, all written in PHP. These applications communicate with each other through an API. There is one application on top to let them communicate with clients from outside the server, globally it looks like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPsiW.png]

The app who has to handle the hit responds in JSON to App 1, App 1 generates an appropriate answer to the hit, such as a webpage, image or just plain JSON, based on the information in the JSON.

If an application needs to communicate with another application, he will send a HTTP-request with cURL. Basically he becomes a client on his own server. I know this method consumes more resources than using a direct function, like Include or Require. But when I use these functions, I lose a lot of the standalone-principles.

The reason I like to stick with my standalone-principles is that I like to work with external junior programmers. I don’t want them to be obliged to use things like OOP, Classes etc. I want to say to them: “This is the input, I expect the output to be this, create a PHP-application to achieve it”.

My questions are:

- Does the HTTP-method use many more resources compared to direct functions like Include or Require?
- Are there better ways, besides Include or Require, to build a internal API with PHP?!

Comment: Yes, going out over HTTP to your own application requires many more resources on top of just instantiating something directly.  I recently did a project which cut our load in half by moving away from hitting our own web services, in favor of instantiating those service classes directly.  Now, how much this matters depends greatly on your application and what it does.  Experiment.  That separation can be important as you scale, but there are often many choices to make when scaling.

Comment: -1 for the fact that you are shielding devs from actual "good" features for no valid reason. Nevertheless, I'll provide a solution for you.

Comment: not counting the overhead incurred with your web server or any of the support architecture you can run `<?php echo memory_get_usage(); ?>` to somewhat quantify what your methodology is costing you in terms of memory.

Comment: All you're talking about is writing a muti-tiered system. It's nothing new. Just write a back-end PHP system that generates JSON or SOAP or some other standardised output that can be read in easily by another system. Nothing new here. But in all seriousness: even a junior dev should be expected to know about things like OOP and classes. If they don't then the odds are very high that they're writing poor quality code. That doesn't just mean poor technique, it also means vulnerable to error and attack. Don't cut corners on your budget on this; it will cost you later.

Comment: What @Spudley said, + "use things like OOP, Classes"... Classes are part of OOP, and I get the impression that we're dealing with ludditism here. What exactly IS the problem you have with OOP? It's required by even the most junior PHP jobs in the industry right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers to your questions:

1. It depends on a lot of things, including, but not limited to:

   - The location of your server
   - The number of nodes, and the quality of the nodes, between your servers
   - The latency of your servers
   - The format you use to convey the information

   To give you an idea of how this all pans out, consider the simple case where all your apps are virtual hosts on the same box. You are using `curl` to hit `myserver.com/app1/` from app2. What you may not be aware of is that this:

   - Is forcing a DNS lookup to `myserver.com`
   - Will travel all the way out to the public interface of your router before looping back in

   Instead of the earlier scenario, consider this one: you are using `curl` to hit `myserver2.com` from `myserver.com`. The two are on a VPN together, but both also have a public interface where `myserver.com` and `myserver2.com` are bound to (respectively). The result? You're going over WAN when you could have tunneled through VPN.

In all cases, you will incur anywhere between ~10ms and ~50ms of latency per call, if the calls go to WAN.

"Direct functions" like `include` solve a completely different problem, but yes, they cut down on the entire HTTP request overhead. Direct instantiation should always be preferred, and your second best option should be caching the HTTP calls using something like `redis`.

Question two has a simple answer: *Yes, not building one*. If by an "internal API", you are building nothing more than a load-balancer, consider just using a load balancer. If you are building content mediation, consider abstracting it away and letting your devs actually **do what they're good at**.